# How to create source maps without mappings

Tags: javascript, source-maps

I have made a transpiler which ensures that line numbers of both source and output programs are the same. For example, `import` is transformed into `require` keeping lines positions the same. How can I effectively generate a source map without having to build an AST? All I want is to specify that the source file is `../src/index.js` and I thought because the line numbers are the same, I only need to add a mapping to indicate a line such as `1 -> 1:0`, `2 -> 2:0` and `sourceContent` but it does not work as the debugger will stop at the line but not move along statements in it. Is there any easy way to perform this without having to analyse code? E.g., generated map

```
{
  "version":3,
  "sources":["../test/fixture/src/run.js"],
  "names":[],
  "mappings":"AAAA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA",
  "sourcesContent":[
    "import main from '.'\n\ndebugger\n\n(async () => {\n  debugger\n  await main()\n})()"
],
  "file":"run.js"
}
```

[example](https://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/#base64,bGV0IG1haW4gPSByZXF1aXJlKCcuJyk7IGlmIChtYWluICYmIG1haW4uX19lc01vZHVsZSkgbWFpbiA9IG1haW4uZGVmYXVsdDsKCmRlYnVnZ2VyCgooYXN5bmMgKCkgPT4gewogIGRlYnVnZ2VyCiAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coMTIzKTsgYXdhaXQgbWFpbigpCn0pKCkKLy8jIHNvdXJjZU1hcHBpbmdVUkw9cnVuLmpzLm1hcA==,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIi4uL3Rlc3QvZml4dHVyZS9zcmMvcnVuLmpzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0E7QUFDQTtBQUNBO0FBQ0EiLCJzb3VyY2VzQ29udGVudCI6WyJpbXBvcnQgbWFpbiBmcm9tICcuJ1xuXG5kZWJ1Z2dlclxuXG4oYXN5bmMgKCkgPT4ge1xuICBkZWJ1Z2dlclxuICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygxMjMpOyBhd2FpdCBtYWluKClcbn0pKCkiXSwiZmlsZSI6InJ1bi5qcyJ9,aW1wb3J0IG1haW4gZnJvbSAnLicKCmRlYnVnZ2VyCgooYXN5bmMgKCkgPT4gewogIGRlYnVnZ2VyCiAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coMTIzKTsgYXdhaXQgbWFpbigpCn0pKCk=)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  Can you please explain a little bit more?  At a very cursory glance, it sounds like you want a source map without a map.  Isn't that just source?

Comment: e.g., I remap imports to require statement, but everything else is the same. And I don't care about mapping `import` lines since the debugger doesn't stop there anyway. I've added a link to the questions.